# Cisco find switch and port of remote device [port-channel, vpc]

Tags: port, router, cisco, vpc

What I have:
hostname, ip of Toolserver, CLI of every router/switch in the network.
What I want:
I'd like to know on which port on which switch the Toolserver is connected.

What I have done:

CLI on Gateway adress of the Toolserver IP:

```
sh ip arp *ip*
```

Now I have a MAC Address and an Interface.

```
sh mac address-table address *MAC*
```

When I now look at the ports I see that:

```
Po3997
```

That vPC status is up and is working but that doesn't really help me.
I see the interface members of that channel. But how does that help me?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I found it out myself.

```
sh int po{port-channel nummber}
```

Now I know the member in this channel: Eth1/xx und Eth2/xx

```
sh cdp nei
```

Now I know the hostname of the devices connected on that port.

Now I need to redo those 2 steps 1 more time, because there is another switch between.

Now I can do

```
sh mac address-table address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
```